# Assign a math operator to a variable - VB

Tags: vb.net, variables, operator-keyword

I'm doing a pretty simple project for a class and just wondering if I'm going about it in the right way. We are making a clone of the Windows calculator.

For each of the math operators my code is as follows:

```
Private Sub btnPlus_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPlus.Click
    If opPressed = True Then
        Select Case (opType)
            Case "+"
                txtField.Text = CStr(CDbl(opStore) + CDbl(txtField.Text))
            Case "-"
                txtField.Text = CStr(CDbl(opStore) - CDbl(txtField.Text))
            Case "*"
                txtField.Text = CStr(CDbl(opStore) * CDbl(txtField.Text))
            Case "/"
                txtField.Text = CStr(CDbl(opStore) / CDbl(txtField.Text))
        End Select
        opPressed = True
        opType = "+"
    Else
        opStore = txtField.Text
        txtField.Clear()
        opPressed = True
        opType = "+"
    End If
End Sub
```

Is there a way I could simply store an operator in a variable, and then have a line: `txtField.Text = CStr(CDbl(opStore) variableHere CDbl(txtField.Text))`? I am already storing what operator is used, so is there any easy way to convert that out of a string, and use it as an operator?

Comment: You are already going about it the right way. It is possible to do what you are asking but it is not "easy".

Comment: Alright, thank you. 

Can you point me in the right direction for the other method? I'd love to check it out, even if this wouldn't be the ideal situation for implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want something different, you could have a member variable of type `Dictionary(Of String, Func(Of Double, Double, Double))` to associate a string operator with the actual logic for the operator:

```
Private _ops = New Dictionary(Of String, Func(Of Double, Double, Double))() From {
    {"+", Function(x, y) x + y},
    {"-", Function(x, y) x - y},
    {"*", Function(x, y) x * y},
    {"/", Function(x, y) x / y}
}
```

And then use that in your button click handler:

```
Dim op = _ops(opType)
txtField.Text = CStr(op(CDbl(opStore), CDbl(txtField.Text))
```

Comment: Much more elegant than what I have been doing! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use NCalc for this - http://ncalc.codeplex.com/

```
string fullExpression;
string opType = "+";

fullExpression = opStore + opType + txtField.Text;
Expression e = new Expression(fullExpression);

txtField.Text = e.Evaluate().ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you! Since I need to submit this for a class I'm shooting to avoid outside libraries, but I might have to play around with NCalc a bit in my free time - looks pretty cool!