# how to code a user input operator

Tags: .net, vb.net

Hey I'm try to code in a user input operator using the if else statement.

```
If (Operator == "")
    Operator = + ;

Else if (Operator == "")
     Operator = - ;

Else if (Operator == "")
     Operator = * ;
```

This is what I think it should be. Thanks for the help.

Comment: ...what?  What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I can't even tell which language this is meant to be.

Comment: No, you cant then do `z = A operator B`, see [Assign a math operator to a variable - VB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22236677/assign-a-math-operator-to-a-variable-vb)

Comment: What condition are you checking for? All of them are the same.

Comment: I'm trying to add a user input operator, were the user can enter there choice of operations like +, -, *, /

Comment: @RobertWilliams So you want to replace one operator with another?? Am I right there??

Comment: Yes if the user choose to. I would like for the user to enter any operation into a text box and be able to add, subtract, multiple or divid the numbers they choose

Comment: Multiple numbers or just two numbers? cause you might need to think of order of operation if allow more than two values to be acted on.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to perform an operation on a series of values based on an operator that you have specified as a string, right?

In that case, you could define a custom function based on the value of the operator. For example something like this, assuming that you want to operate over two values:

```
Dim OperatorFunc as Func(of Integer, Integer, Integer) 
Dim TheOperator as String

TheOperator = "*"  'Just an example, you get the value from anywhere

If (TheOperator = "+")
    OperatorFunc = Function(x as Integer, y as Integer) x+y
Else if (TheOperator = "-")
     OperatorFunc = Function(x as Integer, y as Integer) x-y
Else if (TheOperator = "*")
     OperatorFunc = Function(x as Integer, y as Integer) x*y
End if
```

Then you use it like this:

```
Dim Result as Integer
Result = OperatorFunc(2, 3)
```

This is a basic example, you could use also a dictionary of functions instead of a cascade of if-elses (which would be also more readable).